# Use tapply and show results on two criteria

Tags: r, apply, tapply

I want to create a table the takes the sum of the amount of state taxes the residents each town contributes by the census block income group and by town. I model this with the following data.

```
Town<-c("Andover","Andover","Burlington","Burlington","Burlington","Burlington","Cheshire")
Category<-c("Low","Middle","High","Low","Middle","Middle","Low")
Value<-c(100,350,230,450,100,200,50)
all<-data.frame(Town,Category,Value)

t1<-tapply(all$Value[all$Category=="Low"],all$Town[all$Category=="Low"],sum)
t2<-tapply(all$Value[all$Category=="Middle"],all$Town[all$Category=="Middle"],sum)
t3<-tapply(all$Value[all$Category=="High"],all$Town[all$Category=="High"],sum)
t4<-cbind(t1,t2,t3)
```

In my actual dataset though the length of the individual tapply files is not the same length.  For example, t1 would have 19 entries, and t3 would have 55. As such I cannot cbind the results. Unfortunately, I cannot recreate this problem with the modeled data.

Regardless, how could I create the t4 table without having to use a for loop or multiple tapply and merge functions?

Essentially I would want to use a function like table

```
#i.e. 
table(all$Town,all$AMIBand)
```

that replaces the counts of occurrences with the sums of a third column, which in this case would be

```
all$Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want something like this:

```
 dcast(all, Town ~ Category, value.var="Value", fun.aggregate=sum)
```